# Spring Boot + Docker database initialization not working

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to set up database initialization for a MySQL in Spring Boot via the basic data.sql and schema.sql files. I've read through various answers and documentation and I believe I've handled all the usual suspects.

I've tried:

- Setting spring.sql.init.mode=always (because the database isn't embedded)
- Setting spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
- Setting spring.datasource.data=classpath:data.sql (ofc the file is in the resources folder)
- Setting spring_jpa_hibernate_ddl-auto=create

Nothing works, nothing changes, the tables are created but they are always blank. I'm starting to think it's got something to do with Docker, but I'm not sure why that would be the case.

Here is the data.sql file:

```
INSERT INTO `work_position` VALUES (1,'Android developer'),
(2,'iOS developer'),
(3,'Backend developer'),
(4,'QA engineer'),
(5,'Human resources manager'),
(6,'Project manager'),
(7,'Designer'),
(8,'Chief technology officer'),
(9,'Chief executive officer'),
(10,'Business secretary'),
(11,'Sales agent'),
(12,'DEV OPS engineer'),
(13,'Innovation manager'),
(14,'Web developer');

...
```

Didn't want to post the whole file, but it's literally just several insert statements. I run the app and db via Docker Compose; there are no errors in the output, a couple of warnings but nothing notable.

Comment: Are you copying sql file correctly into Docker?

Comment: I wonder if you have connected to the database server, but not selected a database. Could you try a `USE mydatabase;` at the start of your `INSERT` block?

Comment: Also try `docker compose logs` - maybe there would be some clues there.

Comment: I suggest you debug at `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#execute` and checkout what is going wrong. That should be easy to figure out.